# Crontab is not running properly with .py

Tags: python, cron

I'm trying to run a .py with crontab in every minute but it's not working.

Crontab;

```
MAILTO="" 
*/1 * * * * /home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py
```

Bot.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from TwitterFollowBot import TwitterBot
my_bot = TwitterBot()

from TwitterFollowBot import TwitterBot
my_bot = TwitterBot("config.txt")  

from TwitterFollowBot import TwitterBot   
my_bot = TwitterBot()
my_bot.sync_follows()

from TwitterFollowBot import TwitterBot    
my_bot = TwitterBot()
my_bot.auto_rt("@ShoutGamers", count=2200)
```

Path;

```
/home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py
```

Crontab log;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py", line 5, in <module>
    my_bot = TwitterBot()
  File "/home/TwitterFollowBot/TwitterFollowBot/__init__.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.bot_setup(config_file)
  File "/home/TwitterFollowBot/TwitterFollowBot/__init__.py", line 78, in bot_setup
    with open(config_file, "r") as in_file:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config.txt'
```

Comment: Looks like cron is running it. I'm guessing the issue is that the import fails when run with `cron`. Try changing the cron line to `*/1 * * * * /home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py 2>/tmp/twitterBot.log` and then [edit] your question and add any error messages printed to `/tmp/twitterBot.log`. Also, please [edit] your question and tell us how you are creating the crontab. Is it via `sudo crontab -e`? Manually editing a file in `/etc/cron`? Your own user's `crontab -e`? Oh, and the `*/1` isn't doing anything, just use `*` alone.

Comment: I'm using crontab --e 
Do you mean add this whole line to crontab as a one line? 
*/1 * * * * /home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py 2>/tmp/twitterBot.log

Comment: @terdon♦ I just updated the question with log. :)

Comment: It says "No such file or directory" but there is a files named 'config.txt' and it works when i run it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works when you run it manually because you are probably running it from the directory containing the `config.txt` file. Your crontab will be running from the home directory of the user whose crontab it is. So, if you ran `crontab -e` as the user `foo`, it will be looking for `/home/foo/config.txt`.

The simplest fix would be to use the full path in your python script:

```
my_bot = TwitterBot("/home/foo/config.txt")
```

Also, you script looks kind of strange. Why so many imports? Why reinitiate the bot so many times? I can't test it, but are you sure you don't just want:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

from TwitterFollowBot import TwitterBot
my_bot = TwitterBot("config.txt")  
my_bot.sync_follows()
my_bot.auto_rt("@ShoutGamers", count=2200)
```

Comment: I just followed a tutorial that's how I did it.

Will it work if I use it like this? 

#!/usr/bin/env python

from TwitterFollowBot import TwitterBot
my_bot = TwitterBot("/home/FollowTwitterbot/config.txt")  
my_bot.sync_follows()
my_bot.auto_rt("@ShoutGamers", count=2200)

Comment: Heh, you're welcome. As for your first comment, yes I think it should. Unless there is something very weird in the module you're using, importing it once should do the trick. And redefining `my_bot` *should* start a new instance without the configuration loaded, so I don't see how your original code could have worked. Might be something strange in the module you're using though and I have very little python knowledge anyway, so try it and find out!

Comment: Yeah, it's working now. Thanks again. Btw do you know how to add multiple phrases? currently it automatically retweets on twitter if someone use "@ShoutGamers"  I really need to be able to add two or 3 phrases.

Comment: @IsuruNuwanSubasinghe I have no idea where your phrases are defined. I would just have it tweet a variable and have the phrases there. That's going off topic though since it's a pute Python question and nothing to do with Ubuntu.  You could ask on [so], or visit [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room). You're probably looking for something like [this](https://www.smallsurething.com/multi-line-strings-in-python/).